# Getting all Aura:Attribute meta data from lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, metadata

I am creating a lightning componente to show all meta data of other lightning components in the org. I am stuck at getting aura:attribute's meta data details like name, type and default.

There is not much to move ahead on this already tried with [AuraDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_auradefinitionbundle.htm) Buldle objec. No attribute meta data present. Also tried to get though using some Regex but not easy to consider all scenarios here.

Any one worked on something similar? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question and add relevant information.

Comment: Yes, added details. Not much to move ahead on this front apart from Sobject defintions, which does not help much

Answer (score 1):

As of today (Winter 18) there is no API available to describe the contents of lightning components or programmatically determine their public attributes and/or methods. If you are feeling ambitious you can query the `AuraDefinition` object using SOQL and parse the `Source` field on all attributes with `DefType` of `"COMPONENT"` to find attribute details.

Comment: Yes. I tried same.Could not find very convincing Regex that can give all the details. Dont want to make this an overhead task for admin-dev to be kept as JSON etc. Trying to find an automated way